# Sum of derivatives

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

Let
$$f(x)=\frac{x}{e^x−1}$$
if $x≠0$, and let $f(0)=0$. Let $f^{(n)}$ denote the $n^{th}$ derivative of $f$. Then find the sum
$$f^{(1)}(0)+f^{(3)}(0)+f^{(5)}(0)+\ldots$$

Comment: The sum is $-1/2$. Note that $f(0)=1$ not $0$.

Comment: Have you missed something? Maybe the sum is $\frac{1}{1!}f^{(1)}(0)+\frac{1}{3!}f^{(3)}(0)+\frac{1}{5!}f^{(5)}(0)+\cdots$.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Bernoulli generating function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_number)

> $$ g(x) = \frac{xe^{nx}}{e^{x}-1} $$

with $n=0$.

Comment: And like a schmuck,I'm sitting here differentiating 5 straight times using the product rule until I went back and read it again.......lol Alternatively,of course, you can use the Taylor expansion.